# Can we get Route on Mapbox map without internet/withpout calling api call to mapbox?

Tags: java, android

I am getting route on mapbox by calling api to mapbox but i need it to work with out internet means is ther any option to get route on map without calling api in androidstudio?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Offline navigation in the docs which is an available functionality in `Mapbox` [Offline navigation - Mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/navigation/overview/offline-routing/)

Comment: i have seen above link already but i did not understand and it was in .swift files please help me for routing on downloaded maps(i have downloaded some region it is working fine for whatever latlongs is given  in my code it is showing on map with in downloaded boundaries).I need route between two location on that downloadedregion with out calling api call to mapbox(without internet)

Comment: You can take a look at this link [link text](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/overview/offline-routing/) , you can actually download the map routes for offline use and it's in java.

Comment: Do i need to pay any payment for Offline Routing Access token,in above link they mentioned like only for Enterprised Customers only.

Comment: I believe you can use a free key but for a certain number of requests. It will be useful in development process.

Comment: Thanks for update,but in my search i found that all getroute method calling api with respect to source and destination latlongs along with accesstoken and response is taken for drawing route on map.

Comment: I need solution that                                                                                               
for downloaded region/offline maps get route on two points with out calling api and get response process.(calling to https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/driving/78.40011,17.495742;78.413573,17.492331?access_token=sk.eyJ1IjoibmFnYXNhaSIsImEiOiJjanRqdjBycm0xMHZ0NGFvNmM3bnlqZW9jIn0.GcaTHCYtRuDnvuNntRaUYg&geometries=polyline6&overview=full) it gives response for given source and destination points when device has Internet ON mode. I want route with out Internet.